# Material-ui vertical divider in a button

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui

I'm just trying to put a vertical divider between text and an icon in a button, but I keep getting a horizontal one. My (simplified) component is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Clear } from '@material-ui/icons';

export default function CancelButton({handleClick}) {

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} color="primary" variant="contained">
      <Typography>Cancel</Typography>
      <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem={true} />
      <Clear />
    </Button>
  );
}
```

which ends up looking like

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is you imported Divider from Button

```
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

Comment: If you use typescript, errors will appear immediately :D

Comment: Can you recommend a good resource for including typescript in the React/Material-ui stack?

Comment: You can start with an example from material-ui: 
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript